# C# + Amazon Web Services: Не десериализуется XML

Tags: c#, xml, amazon, .net, amazon-web-services

Всем привет. Нужна помощь. Ситуация следующая.

Я пишу приложение, которое использует API Amazon'а. Оно формирует и посылает запросы на ItemLookup в Amazon Web Services. В ответ получает xml с корневым элементом ItemLookupResponse.

Чтобы не парсить его, я использую Proxy, который предоставляет WSDL от Амазона, и хочу десериализовать то, что получаю в ответ на запрос. Вот тут подробно описано всё, что я делаю (habrahabr.ru/post/151917/).

Проблемы начались ещё с попытки всё это скомпилировать. Студия заявила мне следующее:

```
Невозможно создать временный класс (результат=1).
error CS0030: Преобразование типа "WindowsFormsApplication1.Amazon.ImageSet[]" в "WindowsFormsApplication1.Amazon.ImageSet" невозможно
error CS0029: Неявное преобразование типа "WindowsFormsApplication1.Amazon.ImageSet" в "WindowsFormsApplication1.Amazon.ImageSet[]" невозможно
```

Оказалось, что это баг в генераторе прокси. Вот тут описаны решения:
http://webservices20.blogspot.co.il/2010/02/net-wcf-bug-cannot-convert-type-to.html

Я пошёл в прокси и ручками изменил typeof(ImageSet) на typeof(ImageSet[]). Всё стало запускаться.

В чём проблема сейчас. Вот кусок кода, где полученный документ десериализуется:

```
        XmlDocument document = RetrieveXmlResponse(AWSrequest); 
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemLookupResponse));
        ItemLookupResponse response;
        try
        {
            response = (ItemLookupResponse)ser.Deserialize(new XmlNodeReader(document.DocumentElement));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Caught Exception: " + ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

В блоке Try происходит ошибка. Метод ser.CanDeserialize говорит, что оно не десериализуемо. Ошибку глаголит простую:

> В документе XML присутствует ошибка.

Ума не приложу, в чём может быть проблема. Полученный документ в порядке, если его открыть в дебаге, то там корректный XML с верным корневым элементом, открывается в средстве визуализации XML.

http://pastebin.com/e9W7NwYp - Вот так выглядит ответ Амазона, который кладётся в document.

Вот так выглядит класс в прокси:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3082")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01")]
    public partial class ItemLookupResponse {

        private OperationRequest operationRequestField;

        private Items[] itemsField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public OperationRequest OperationRequest {
            get {
                return this.operationRequestField;
            }
            set {
                this.operationRequestField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Items")]
        public Items[] Items {
            get {
                return this.itemsField;
            }
            set {
                this.itemsField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Vaskrol ну вы хотя бы покажите, что у вас за xml и что такое ItemLookupResponse

Comment: @DreamChild Я обновил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл, в чём проблема. При создании десериалайзера надо обязательно указывать пространство имён, вот так:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemLookupResponse),    "http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01");
```